# Opening new external URL as Pop up in frame(not iframe) using Jquery from area tag (generated from SSRS Report)

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, iframe, reporting-services

I have an area control which is having href="http://google.com" I want to open this URL as pop in frame.
Area code is as follows:

```
<area tabindex="61" alt="" id="ar1" title="" href="http://google.com"  
style="text-decoration:none;" target="_top" shape="poly"     
coords="123,169,123,237,146,237,146,169"></area>
```

I am not generating any area control. The area control is being generated from SSRS report and this SSRS report is not assigning any id for area.

I have googled a lot but does not get success so I have posted it here.

SSRS is generating report like the below image.

 .[image]

SSRS is generating dynamic URL and each bar having different URL and it may be any server name in the globe (e.g. 1 bar has URL of google another has URL of apple)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have removed **target="_top"** and it start working for me.

This application having too many Frame, frameset & iframe nesting. somewhere it was causing issue due to **target="_top"**.

Answer (score 1):

you can use like this... I am giving a theme how can you achieve this...

```
<html> 
<head> 
    <title>Test IFrame SRC by Javascript </title> 
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script> 
    <script> 
        $(document).ready(function () { 
            $("#button").click(function () { 
                $("#frame").attr("src", "http://www.dotnetschools.com/"); 
            }) 
        }); 
    </script> 
</head> 
<body> 
    <div id="mydiv"> 
        <iframe id="frame" src="" width="100%" height="300"></iframe>         
  </div> 
    <button id="button">Load</button>  
</body> 
</html>
```

As you can see on above example on button click, I am opening a url inside a iframe. you can just do that.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for posting your code. I have tried this but I does not resolve my issue. As I have to open it on area.

And I am not using Iframe. I am using frame. and I need that src of frame should be external URL.